# Implement a monotonic integer in C++ without having to overload basic operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, wrapper

I would like to implement an integer class that only increases in time. So, if `i` is a monotonic integer with value `v`, it cannot be assigned a value less than `v`. I can implement this using a class that overloads the `=` operator, but I don't want to redefine all the useful operators for `int` like `+,-,+=,-=` etc. Is there a way to do this? I am not sure if it is possible using a conversion to `int` or a `wrapper class`.

Comment: The point you cast to `int&` you lose this limitation.

Comment: you will have to redefine almost all operators otherwise the only way to prevent the number from getting smaller is making it `const`

Comment: making it const of course, does not achieve the objective, as I would like to increase it.

Comment: There are libraries that make this easier. Boost.Operators used to be a favourite of mind.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for boost wrappers for native data types. Can you answer the question by showing an example of how to do it in boost?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to re-define the operators.
Create a custom class and only define methods which support the functionality you require. For example,

```
class IncInt{

    int m_value;

public:
    explicit IncInt(int start) : m_value(start) {}
    const IncInt& operator=(const IncInt& obj)
    {
        if(this == &obj)
            return *this;

        if(obj.m_value > m_value)
            m_value = obj.m_value;
        return *this;
    }

    const IncInt& operator=(const int n)
    {
        if(n > m_value)
            m_value = n;
        return *this;
    }

    IncInt operator+(const int n) const
    {
        return IncInt(m_value + n);
    }

    // additional functions
};
```

Comment: what do I do to make the following code work (the whole point is that I don't want to define all the basic operators, but still use them.)
    IncInt a(0);
    IncInt b(7);
    a = b + 3;

Will defining a cast to integer, always work?

Comment: You would need to define the operation `IncInt + int` for it to work. There is simply no way you can tell C++ to treat an integer different than what it is. I added `IncInt operator+(const int n) const`.

Comment: I tried defining the cast to int operator : ` operator int() { return m_value; }`. Then `a=b+3` works. But, you are right. Seems like I will have to define the operators that I am going to use.